# DIfferent widths of parts of a multipart node in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

Is there a way to define different width of different parts of a multipart node? I did not provide a MWE because I think the question is very restricted in scope -- all I want is to set the minimum width of the first part to something and the minimum width of the second part to something else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not possible to define different `minimum width` for every part in a multipart node, but if you just want a two or three part nodes, you can play with `labels`. Next code shows a two and three part node with different width in every part:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[draw, fill=red!30, text width=3cm, 
     label={[text width=1.8cm, draw, align=center, fill=blue!30, 
           yshift=-\pgflinewidth]This is the first part of the text}]
     {This is the second part of my text};

\node[draw, fill=red!30, text width=3cm, 
     label={[text width=1.8cm, draw, align=center, fill=blue!30, 
           yshift=-\pgflinewidth]This is the first part of the text},
     label={[text width=2.2cm, draw, align=center, fill=green!30,
           yshift=\pgflinewidth]below:This is the third of the text}] 
     at (4,0) {This is the second part of my text};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks much. I have a horizontal 3 part and I wanted to set the width of the first part different than the following two. I will play around with labels.

Comment: @ozsu Why do you want `multipart` node? just three nodes one beside the other or a `matrix` node will do the same.

Comment: @ignasil will try that as well. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can set styles for each part of a multipart node.  Without a MWE here it is hard to make an example.  The nodes I have been working on are 9-part nodes, so they don't really work for an MWE.

[Here's a link that shows how to do it.](https://sstrhsrtj.blogspot.com/2019/04/tikz-styles-that-set-nodepart-styles.html)

`every text node part/.style={text width = 2cm}` is the critical code, where `text` is the name of the main part of the node, and then you have other named parts.  For example, if you have a node part called `two`, you would do `every two node part/.style={text width = 1cm}`